# how to get output bitmap from GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, bitmap, glsurfaceview

I have android Hello Effect sample in front of me. I can see how it applying different effects on `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView`. All done successfully. I wonder how can I get the output bitmap from `GLSurfaceView`?
this is the code:

```
   private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private Effect mEffect;
    private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
    private int mImageWidth;
    private int mImageHeight;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    int mCurrentEffect;

    public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
        mCurrentEffect = effect;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /**
         * Initialize the renderer and tell it to only render when
         * explicity requested with the RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY option
         */
        glSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(this);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mCurrentEffect = R.id.none;

    }



    private void loadTextures() {
        // Generate textures
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

        // Load input bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.puppy);
        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        // Set texture parameters
        GLToolbox.initTexParams();
    }

    private void initEffect() {
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }
        /**
         * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
         */
        switch (mCurrentEffect) {

            case R.id.none:
                break;

            case R.id.autofix:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
                break;

            case R.id.bw:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
                mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
                mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
                break;

            case R.id.brightness:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
                mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.contrast:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
                mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
                break;

            case R.id.crossprocess:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
                break;

            case R.id.documentary:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
                break;

            case R.id.duotone:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
                mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
                mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.filllight:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
                break;

            case R.id.fisheye:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.flipvert:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
                break;

            case R.id.fliphor:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
                break;

            case R.id.grain:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.grayscale:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
                break;

            case R.id.lomoish:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
                break;

            case R.id.negative:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                break;

            case R.id.posterize:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                break;

            case R.id.rotate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
                break;

            case R.id.saturate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.sepia:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                break;

            case R.id.sharpen:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
                break;

            case R.id.temperature:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
                break;

            case R.id.tint:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
                break;

            case R.id.vignette:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }

    }

    private void applyEffect() {
        mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        } else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            //Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        setCurrentEffect(item.getItemId());
        glSurfaceView.requestRender();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the pixels back with `glReadPixels()` after you're done rendering, but before `eglSwapBuffers()` is called.  You're using GLSurfaceView, which does the buffer-swap for you when `onDrawFrame()` returns, so you'll need to do the capture right at the end of `onDrawFrame()`.

You can find an example that saves the current GLES framebuffer to a PNG in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  See the [EglSurfaceBase#saveFrame()](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java#L157) method (you can ignore the mEglCore test at the top).

Answer (score 0):

To get the output bitmap from the glSurfaceView, you need to make use of glReadPixes(). When using glReadPixels(), ensure you are calling it from the renderer thread. it woont work if you call from main thread. Here is the code to get the output bitmap.

```
   public Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int w, int h) {
    w = screenWidth;
    h = screenHeight;


    int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
    int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);
    try {


        GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
        int offset1, offset2;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            offset1 = i * w;
            offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch (GLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
```